# How to add text to splitLayout

Tags: r, visualization, shiny

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot(plot(cars, main = "Cars"))
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot(plot(pressure, main = "Pressure"))
  output$plot3 <- renderPlot(plot(AirPassengers))
}

# Equal sizing
ui <- splitLayout(
  plotOutput("plot1"),
  plotOutput("plot2")
)
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here I have a splitLayout with 2 plots, and on top of each plot, I want to be able to insert a caption, i.e. "Data 1" on top of `plot1` and "Data 2" on top of `plot2`. Is there an easy way to add captions? I've tried `textInput` but that didn't work out. Wondering if there's an easier way?

Comment: Why don't you just add a title to the plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just put a tagList inside the split containers with literal values

```
ui <- splitLayout(
  tagList(tags$p("plot 1"), plotOutput("plot1")),
  tagList(tags$p("plot 2"), plotOutput("plot2"))
)
```

or you can add textOuputs

```
ui <- splitLayout(
  tagList(textOuput("plot1label"), plotOutput("plot1")),
  tagList(textOuput("plot2label"), plotOutput("plot2"))
)
```